# What are possible values of 'relationship' field returned from Facebook Graph API /me/family query?

Tags: facebook, api

Can't seem to find it in the docs or here.  Starting to think this list does not exist.

I'm looking for a complete list of (or a way of generating such a list) possible values that can be returned in the 'relationship' field of Facebook Graph API queries like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/family?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

(You will of course need to supply your own ACCESS_TOKEN to see the results of such a query.  The API explorer is good for that kind of thing - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As described here](http://yourpalmark.github.com/facebook-actionscript-api/docs/com/facebook/graph/data/fql/user/FQLUser.html#family) -

> relationship -- A string describing the type of relationship. Can be one of parent, mother, father, sibling, sister, brother, child, son, daughter.

Comment: Does that documentation come from FB or from experience?

Comment: I couldn't find any official doc for this. So must be from experience. I found the same thing [here](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL:user), and that site claims to be by developers for developers. So I'm pretty sure it's from experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [FQL family documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/family), the `relationship` field is listed as a string. These usually are not enumerated anywhere.